# Manage Docker image volumes

Tags: docker

Command below brings list of volumes on my machine.

```
docker volume ls
```

How to know which volume belongs to which image and which one belongs to nothing and can be safely removed?

I would like to transfer my system that consists of Docker images and volumes transfer to another pc. I can save images by executing command:

```
docker image save my_image -o my_image_archive.tar
```

But how to transfer volumes with data to another pc in order to make transferred images to use volumes with original data?

Comment: This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66505185/1423507). There is no default `docker` functionality to export volumes and `docker export` does not export the contents of volumes associated to a container.

Comment: If the `volumes` are in use (e.g. a container mounting the volumes) you can [`docker volume prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/) to remove unused containers. To list the volumes mounted by containers you can format the `docker inspect` command i.e.: `for container in $(docker container ls -a --format {{.ID}}); do docker inspect $container --format='{{.Name}} {{range .Mounts}}{{.Name}}{{end}}'; done`